# How to un-mirror an objects sides?

Tags: uv, mirror, uv-image-editor

[image]

Apologizes for the terrible wording in this! I am unsure how I got to this point but my garment seems to be mirrored on both sides. I've tried to texture one side different so that maybe that will give me both sides of the garment in the UV map area- but it seems to paint on both sides when I do this.

I'm very new to blender so perhaps I have something turned on that is doing this? Any ideas or assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: The question requires more information. If object while texture painting it has strokes being painted on both sides at the same time while all the modifiers were applied and texture paint brush doesn't have symmetry options enabled then islands on UV map intersect.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have "X" Symmetry enabled in the tools panel if you are experiencing this issue while texture painting in Blender.

[image]

Comment: Hi there! I must have a different version of blender as my texture paint mode does not have symmetry options. I turned it off regardless to see if that would help me see both sides of my garment on the UV map and unfortunately it did not.

Comment: @Damuko How did you turn it off if you don't have symmetry options?

Comment: I turned off the symmetry in sculpting mode. That is the only location that had the symmetry mode on it.

Comment: @Damuko That won't matter for texture painting. What version of Blender are you using?